# Dynamic & Kinematic Interaction Problem In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, dotween

ın uploaded "screenshot.png"image , the white box is dynamic rigid body and has mass and gravity , and the hinge under of it has kinematic body and makes a rotation -90 degrees as it shown in "screenshot2.png".
after making DOTween rotation movement in (0.5f second) unfortunately the hinge doesn't throw white box properly .. Should I make it with code by giving force or etc ??
What can I do ? Any suggestion ?

Initial State

[image]

After rotating the hinge object

[image]

I try to make  auto hinge for that white box and throw it smoothly ..

Comment: Please give us more in depth understanding of what you are using and where. Like show us the hinge joint config in inspector.

Comment: @sujoybyte I don't think OP is referring to a `HingeJoint` component. `hinge` rather simply seems to refer o the object that is being rotated by 90°

Comment: hi , thanx for reply but. I solved to problem by changing  transform.DORotate() function with gameObject.getcomponent<Rigidbody2D>()  ,  it is needed not to mix game object(transform) & rigid body structures  for taking right physic replies in the scene ..

Comment: Just wanted to suggest to not use DoTween in a physics environment (except they have something build in to handle it properly by going through the rigidbody) ;) Also this seems such a simple movement that I don't really see a win using DoTween for this